# How to run MongoDB native query (JSON) using Mongo-Java Driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to run below native Queries in my java project using DB.runCommand()

Query1:

```
db.test_temp.insert({entityId:2,columnName1:"columnName2.1",columnName2:"columnName2.2"})
```

Query 2:

```
db.test_temp.updateOne(
   { columnName1: "columnName1" },
   {
     $set: { "columnName1": "columnName1.0" }
   }
);
```

My code:

```
String json="db.test_temp.insert({entityId:2,columnName1:"columnName2.1",columnName2:"columnName2.2"}";
Bson command = new Document("eval",json); 
db.runCommand(command);
```

I also tried from [How to execute MongoDB native query (JSON) using mongo-java-driver only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093563/how-to-execute-mongodb-native-query-json-using-mongo-java-driver-only) but it's not working

Error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in your mentioned link `

> eval command is deprecated and its usage is not advised

According to [this](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/native-query-execution-in-java/6602/5) answer, you can do as follows

```
String json = "{insert : 'collectionName', documents : [{entityId:2,columnName1:'columnName2.1',columnName2:'columnName2.2'}]}";
Document bsonCmd = Document.parse(json);
Document result = db.runCommand​(bsonCmd);
```

Please check `insert` command syntax in [insert docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/insert/#dbcmd.insert)